# Find Generalised vectors $v_2$, $v_3$ $\in$ $R^3$ of A for $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Ok, So I have the following vector
\begin{equation} A =
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

I have found the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$  which has algebraic multiplicity of 3.

But now I want to find the generalised vectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ such that
\begin{equation}
(A - \lambda I)v_2 = v_1, \quad (A - \lambda I)v_3 = v_2
\end{equation}

When I compute this, I get the following

\begin{equation}
v_2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right), \quad v_3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} b \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

for any $a$ and $b$.

Obviously, we cannot find one solution for $a,b$. Would I be correct in saying that we can take any value for $a$ and $b$ so for simplicity, we can just take both $a = b = 0$ because this obviously works for any value of $a$ and $b$?

In addition to this, how do we calculate the Jordan Normal form of A. I have got an idea of how to do it but I don't know why we would do it. This is what I have:

\begin{equation} A =
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

Which was given to me, but how do we actually calculate this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, in addition to the above, how would you calculate the Jordan Normal Form of A? Thanks imranfat for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a minor bug, your ideas are correct.

You eigenvector is $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. You want $v_2$ such that $(A-2I)v_2=v_1$, or, as you said, $\begin{pmatrix}a\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ for arbitrary $a$ (because first generalisd eigenvector is defined up to an eigenvector). For the $v_3$ you want $(A-2I)v_3=v_2$

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},$$
which gives you $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}b\\a-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Now you can make an obvious choice and put $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick for finding eigenvectors for $2$ and $3$ dimensional matrices is to exploit the Cayley-Hamilton theorem (it works for higher dimensions too, but the cost of multiplying the matrices makes it less attractive). The Cayley Hamilton theorem says that if $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $A$, then $p(A) = 0$ (scalars in this equation are considered to be the scalar multiplied by the identity matrix I). Now the characteristic polynomial is given by $p(x) = (x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)\ldots(x - \lambda_n)$, for an $n \times n$ matrix, where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues. So $$p(A) = (A - \lambda_1I)(A - \lambda_2I)\ldots(A - \lambda_nI)$$
(this factorization is possible because $A$ commutes with itself and $I$). So eigenvectors of $\lambda_1$ are found among the columns of the product $(A - \lambda_2I)\ldots(A - \lambda_nI)$

In this case $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 2$, so the eigenvectors of $2$ are in the columns of $$(A - 2I)^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus $(1, 0, 0)$ is an eigenvector. Now $(A - 2I)^2(A - 2I) = 0$, so generalized eigenvectors can be found among the columns of $(A - 2I)$ itself, where we find $(1,0,0)$ again, and $(1,1,0)$.

Alas, it only gives us two generalized eigenvectors, so we have to fall back on the method used by Ross and TZarkrevskiy to find the third. (This is the first matrix I have ever seen fail to provide all three, but I've mostly used it on symmetric matrices, which are guaranteed to have three linearly independent ordinary eigenvectors.)

Comment: Great thanks Paul. It's great to have an other alternative!